Recovering overwritten folder or file without a software in Mac?
I was working on a Wordpress theme locally on Mac MacBook Pro - Sonoma, I tried to update Wordpress core and clicked replace which one removed my custom theme from Wordpress themes directory.
I know there are too many third party softwares like disk drill but I would like to use command line and finder to recover my work.
first I tried a search via grep command in terminal using:
grep -iRl "THEMENAME"

then it gives me a result like this:

When I open Disk Utility I open the disk with finder and I find there the Volumes or TemporaryItems but these folders are 0KB there is no data.
My question is: Where the deleted data goes what methods are used from the third party add ons? So, is there any way to recover my data back?

If an application deletes data/files, they usually are gone.

It was a copy paste method in the morning I just replaced Wordpress over my existing Wordpress files but I didn't know that it will remove themes folder so since there is no shred command used the files must be there around the disk or Im wrong?

If you overwrite the files in Finder, they are gone.

I understand you and thanks for reply but I overwrited only Wordpress which does not have my theme included and extra theme must stay there so I didn't overwrite my work but the parent folder

If you overwrote the parent folder then it gets rid of contents as well.

If you don't have a backup, then overwriting or deleting files is a permanent action.

That's what Time Machine is for. Open the latest Time Machine folder that still contains the data, and copy it. No Time Machine, no fun.

If files and/or directories are overwritten, they are gone and can't be recovered. This also applies to files within a subfolder etc.
While recovery is theoretically possible, it has become significantly less likely to be successful with SSDs, due to the way SSDs manage free/unused blocks.
For this reason, macOS prompts to set up Time Machine and you can even get a Time Machine snapshot stored locally on recent OS without the backup drive attached. Make sure you check that quickly before the snapshot is removed as “old”.
